# Temperature Scale Converter in Prolog

Tags: unit-conversion, prolog

Problem statement:

Write a program that converts all given temperatures from a given input temperature scale to a given output temperature scale. The temperature scales to be supported are Kelvin, Celsius, Fahrenheit, Rankine, Delisle, Newton, Rømer, Réaumur.

Synopsis: `tempconv INPUT_SCALE OUTPUT_SCALE [TEMPERATURE]...`

The `INPUT_SCALE` and `OUTPUT_SCALE` shall be given as follows:

- `K` for Kelvin
- `C` for Celsius
- `F` for Fahrenheit
- `R` for Rankine
- `D` for Delisle
- `N` for Newton
- `Rø` for Rømer
- `Ré` for Réaumur.

Example:

```
tempconv K C 0 273.15 373.15
-273.15
0.0
100.0
```

My solution in Prolog:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S swipl -q -t main

:- use_module(library(clpr)).

convert(S, K, K)  :- member(S, ['Kelvin', 'K']), !.
convert(S, C, K)  :- member(S, ['Celsius', 'C', '°C', '℃']),    {C  = K - 273.15}, !.
convert(S, F, K)  :- member(S, ['Fahrenheit', 'F', '°F', '℉']), {F  = K * 9/5 - 459.67}, !.
convert(S, R, K)  :- member(S, ['Rankine', 'R', '°R']),         {R  = K * 9/5}, !.
convert(S, D, K)  :- member(S, ['Delisle', 'D', '°D']),         {D  = (373.15 - K) * 3/2}, !.
convert(S, N, K)  :- member(S, ['Newton', 'N', '°N']),          {N  = (K - 273.15) * 33/100}, !.
convert(S, D, K)  :- member(S, ['Dalton']),                     {K  = 273.15 * pow((373.15 / 273.15), (D / 100))}, !.
convert(S, Ré, K) :- member(S, ['Réaumur', 'Ré', '°Ré']),       {Ré = (K - 273.15) * 4/5}, !.
convert(S, Rø, K) :- member(S, ['Rømer', 'Rø', '°Rø']),         {Rø = (K - 273.15) * 21/40 + 7.5}, !.
convert(S, _, _)  :- format(user_error, '~s ~a~n', ['Unsupported Temperature Scale', S]), halt(1).

main([InputScale, OutputScale | Argv]) :-
    unicode_nfc(InputScale, InputScaleNormalized),
    unicode_nfc(OutputScale, OutputScaleNormalized),
    main(InputScaleNormalized, OutputScaleNormalized, Argv).
main(InputScale, OutputScale, [TempAtom|Argv]) :-
    atom_number(TempAtom, InputTemperature),
    convert(InputScale, InputTemperature, Kelvin),
    convert(OutputScale, OutputTemperature, Kelvin),
    format('~a~n', OutputTemperature),
    main(InputScale, OutputScale, Argv).
main(_, _, []).
```

I seek to understand if there is anything that can be improved, especially if there is anything that could be done in a more concise way.

Note: For now, error handling (user inputs text instead of a number) is not of concern. I understand that the program terminates silently with exit status `1` when it encounters a non-number, and I'm ok with that.

I'm using SWI-Prolog (see shebang).